# Trying to retrieve data from firestore into recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  XML
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.118"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.132" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfats"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texttype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.118"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.132" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfats"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Model class {

```
private String Type;
private String Fats;

public productsmodel(){}

public productsmodel(String Type, String Fats){
    this.Type = Type;
    this.Fats=Fats;
}


public String getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    Type = type;
}

public String getFats() {
    return Fats;
}

public void setFats(String fats) {
    Fats = fats;
}
```

}

'

public class Products extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView products_list;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
    products_list = findViewById(R.id.products_list);
    //Query
    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Products");

    //Recycler options
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<productsmodel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<productsmodel>().setQuery(query,productsmodel.class).build();
    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<productsmodel, productsviewholder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public productsviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singleitemlist,parent,false);
            return new productsviewholder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull productsviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull productsmodel model) {
            holder.Fats.setText(model.getFats()+"");
            holder.Type.setText(model.getType()+"");

        }
    };
    products_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    products_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

private class productsviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    private TextView Type;
    private TextView Fats;
    public productsviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
        Type=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textfats);
        Fats=itemView.findViewById(R.id.texttype);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}`

- MY products activity keeps crushing after i run it. I am trying to
  add a recycler view in products page which will enable me to retreive
  data from cloud firestore into my recycler view automatically. i have
  attached all the codes related to the function and the error. please
  check it, Thanks!

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs3sn.png ( ERROR SHOWN)

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ePke.png ( MODEL CLASS)

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6aAK.png ( PRODUCTS CLASS)

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeVwZ.png ( XML )

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZxtx.png ( firestore DB)

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/d254o.png (new db)

Comment: Try to set your variables as public so FB can read and build them.

Comment: Thanks for replying bro! in which class? can you please check the other screenshots.

Comment: In the model class

Comment: Can you show what's line 33 in product class?

Comment: Variables are always private. Getters and setters are public

Comment: Stll have the same error @TheDude

Comment: line 33 : Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Products"); @AgustinMagne

Comment: You have a null pointer exception in your firebase instance. You have to call FirebaseFirestore firebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() before using firebase

Comment: Do that in your OnCreate Method

Comment: i have added my code, can you please check it @AgustinMagne

Comment: Thanks :) try that, that should solve you're error.

Comment: Opened the activity but it's empty now @AgustinMagne

Comment: not showing the recycler view @AgustinMagne

Comment: Check your console or logcat for errors, because that's usually a object mapping issue

Comment: no errors found. @AgustinMagne

Comment: If you don't mind, check my answer below as accepted if it solved your problem, and lets continue in it's comment section this discussion please :)

Comment: Sure@AgustinMagne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
FirebaseFirestore firebase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
```

In your onCreate method before using firebase.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217712/discussion-on-answer-by-agustin-magne-trying-to-retrieve-data-from-firestore-int).